# Filter filenames in Maven

Tags: maven-2, filter, maven, filtering, war

I'd like to be able to filter filenames as well as file contents in Maven.

The below snippet enables filtering on file contents, but I need to be able to rename files too.

The usage scenario is that I'd like all static resources in my webapp to be numbered, so they can be treated as different versions by Amazon's CloudFront. Naturally managing the numbers manually would be impractical, so I'd like the build process to do this.

For instance a file called

```
logo_VERSION.jpg
```

would end up being called

```
logo_254.jpg
```

Any ideas if this is possible without writing a custom plugin?

---

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>/src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                ...
```

Comment: As you certainly know, the builtin resource filtering works on the file contents, not the file names. To mangle with the file names, I'm afraid a custom plugin is the only solution, whether you write your own or find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar using the antrun plugin - sometimes you just have to drop back into ant.

pom snippet

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <property name="project.version" value="${project.version}"/>
                            <property name="all.environs" value="DEV1,DEV2,DEV3,DEV4,UAT,PROD"/>
                            <property name="application.environments" 
                                        value="${application.environments}" />

                            <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml" target="setup" />
                            <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml" target="build"/>

                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

build.xml

```
<property name="ant-contrib-jar" value="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>

<target name="setup" unless="ant-contrib.present">
    <echo>Getting ant-contrib</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${ant-contrib-jar}"
         src="http://nexus.inhouse.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>  
</target>

<target name="taskdefs">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${ant-contrib-jar}"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="taskdefs">

    <echo message="basedir: ${basedir}"/>
    <echo message="project.version: ${project.version}"/>

    <foreach list="${application.environments}" target="jar-resources" param="app.env" trim="true">

        <param name="basedir" value="${basedir}" />
        <param name="project.version" value="${project.version}" />

    </foreach>

</target>

<target name="jar-resources">

    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/${app.env}"/>

    <copy todir="${basedir}/target/${app.env}">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources">
            <include name="mail_config.properties"/>
            <include name="service.properties"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <filterset id="applicationFilterSet">
        <filtersfile file="${basedir}/src/main/filters/filter-${app.env}.properties"/>
        <filter token="PROJECT.VERSION" value="${project.version}"/>
    </filterset>

    <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/coresystem.properties"  
        tofile="${basedir}/target/${app.env}/coresystem.properties.${app.env}">
        <filterset refid="applicationFilterSet"/>
    </copy>

    <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/extraProps.properties"  
        tofile="${basedir}/target/${app.env}/extraProps_${app.env}.properties">
        <filterset refid="applicationFilterSet"/>
    </copy>

    <jar destfile="${basedir}/target/MyApp-env-${project.version}-${app.env}.jar"
        basedir="${basedir}/target/${app.env}" />

</target>
```